# Problem when using gtid with MySQL replication

Tags: mysql, replication

I am faced with this problem when using gtid in MySQL replication:

> When @@SESSION.GTID_NEXT is set to a GTID, you must explicitly set it
>   to a different value after a COMMIT or ROLLBACK. Please check
>   GTID_NEXT variable manual page for detailed explanation. Current
>   @@SESSION.GTID_NEXT is 'xxx'"

It makes my slave SQL thread is impossible to run.

I am stuck with it. What is the cause of the problem ?

Comment: There are some my databases include tables using MyISAM storage engine and someone include tables using InnoDB

Comment: I have temporary resolved using follow statements:

    stop slave;
    set gtid_next='automatic';
    start slave;

It resolved the problem but the problem is repeated when the slave continue to execute next gtid get from master.

I have read manual about gtid_next in http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/replication-options-gtids.html I am using MySQL 5.6.20. I guest the cause is some statements is disallowed

I hope one solution is better. I cannot run these statements manually.

Comment: You need to do that as per https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/replication-gtids-failover.html under Section - Injecting empty transactions . If you are adding a server to the replication chain.

Answer (score 1):

I've been having this issue on a new install of 5.6.26. I found a bug report on this and it suggests that the fix is available on 5.6.27 or 5.7.9.

https://bugs.mysql.com/bug.php?id=68525

I've upgraded to 5.6.27 and just watching to see if it happens again.

Hope this helps.